# How to find duplicates not within categories used for pivoting, DAX

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot, dax

I have HR Power Pivot Data imported and organized like this:

Division (same value for all), Branch (7 different), UNIQUEID, STATUS (takes on values OUTLOAN, INLOAN or blank)

If an employee has been transferred, there will be two rows with the same UNIQUEID. One with STATUS OUTLOAN (home position) and another one with STATUS INLOAN (new position).

I need to find the number of people per branch that has been transferred in from outside of the branch (INLOAN), preferrably using DAX and pivottables.

Just to clarify, the people who have moved positions WITHIN a branch should not be counted, just the ones that are on INLOAN from an external branch.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to achieve what you want. Create a measure:

```
EmployeeCount: = COUNTROWS('HR Data')
```

Then add that measure to a pivot table in Excel and then add the `STATUS` column to the filter area of the pivot table and filter on "INLOAN". Add the `BRANCH` column to the row headers of the pivot table.

This will tell you how many people in each branch are on loan from another branch.

Comment: Hi,
I think your solution counts the people that has transferred within the branch as well. I need to omit those and only count the ones that has transferred in from other branches.

Answer (score 0):

So,

Previously, I had calculated the number of duplicate UNIQUEID per branch (ie. the number of internal transfers per branch) as the count of UNIQUEID less the distinct number of UNIQUEID per branch. If one subtracts this from the calculation given by mendosi one should arrive at the number of transfers per branch that are not internal.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is `DISTINCTCOUNT`

The below would give you the distinct count of employees in each branch by counting the UNIQUEID fields unique values.

```
Count:= DISTINCTCOUNT( table_name[UNIQUEID])
```

To expand upon it is the helpful `CALCULATE` statement, the below would do a distinct count of the UniqueID, but only on the rows which have status = Inloan

```
Count:= CALCULATE( DISTINCTCOUNT( table_name[UNIQUEID]), table_name[STATUS] = "INLOAN")
```